# Adding Separator to Breadcrumbs

Tags: php, breadcrumb

I have pieced together a breadcrumbs code that displays child pages/posts and is markedup for schema.

The only thing this code doesn't have is a separator between each link. How can I add a separator in one instance, rather than adding the separator after each individual generated link?

```
function crumbs() {
 if ((is_page() && ! is_category()) || is_archive() || is_single() || is_single()) {
 echo '<div class="crumbs"><span xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">';
 echo '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'">Home</a></span>';
 $post_ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post);
 if ($post_ancestors) {
 $post_ancestors = array_reverse($post_ancestors);
 foreach ($post_ancestors as $crumb)
 echo '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" href="'.get_permalink($crumb).'">'.get_the_title($crumb).'</a></span>';
 }
 if (is_category() || is_single()) {
 $category = get_the_category();
 echo '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->cat_ID).'">'.$category[0]->cat_name.'</a></span>';
 }
 if (!is_category())
 echo '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><span class="crumbs-last" property="v:title">'.get_the_title().'</span></span>';
 echo '</span></div>';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want it like this, however, this can be achieved by CSS.

```
.crumbs > span > span + span {
    margin-left: 1em;
}

.crumbs > span > span + span:before {
    content: '|'; /* or something else */
    *display: inline;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -1em;
    width: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**// EDIT**
If you want it PHP-only, then this is a way to go:

```
function crumbs() {
    if ((is_page() && ! is_category()) || is_archive() || is_single() || is_single()) {
        $crumbs = '';
        $crumbs .= '<div class="crumbs"><span xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">';
        $crumbs .= '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'">Home</a></span>';
        $post_ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post);

        if ($post_ancestors) {
            $post_ancestors = array_reverse($post_ancestors);
            foreach ($post_ancestors as $crumb)
                $crumbs .= '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" href="'.get_permalink($crumb).'">'.get_the_title($crumb).'</a></span>';
        }

        if (is_category() || is_single()) {
            $category = get_the_category();
            $crumbs .= '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->cat_ID).'">'.$category[0]->cat_name.'</a></span>';
        }

        if (!is_category())
            $crumbs .= '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><span class="crumbs-last" property="v:title">'.get_the_title().'</span></span>';

        $crumbs .= '</span></div>';

        $close_crumb = '</span>';
        $open_crumb = '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">';
        $separator = '<span class="separator">|</span>';
        echo str_replace($close_crumb.$open_crumb, $close_crumb.$separator.$open_crumb, $crumbs);
    }
}
```

Yes, it's not nice - but that's due to the whole thing, IMHO.

Comment: @t f Thanks. I am aware of the ability to do this with CSS, but I am looking for a PHP solution. However, this is helpful to those who may be searching for a breadcrumb divider on Google.

Answer (score 0):

If your theme includes a filter for breadcrumbs, you can use code like this in your functions file however theme specific questions are generally off topic here.

```
add_filter('theme_breadcrumb_args_filter', 'customize_separator_breadcrumbs');

function customize_separator_breadcrumbs($args) {
$args['sep'] = ' >> ';
return $args;
}
```

Replace **theme_breadcrumb_args_filter** with your themes breadcrumbs filter.

Comment: Strange, it isn't working for whatever reason.

Comment: It doesn't work unless your parent theme includes a filter for breadcrumbs. If your theme includes a filter for breadcrumbs, you can use code like this in your functions file however theme specific questions are generally off topic here.